# Combining HTAccess rules into one

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hey everyone im trying to use Htaccess to redirect all pages to https:// while keeping the query string without fbclid if it's there.

IE.

- https://www.example.com/?sdfuh
- http://www.example.com/?sdfuh
- www.example.com/?sdfuh
- https://www.example.com/?sdfuh&fbclid=azduh
- http://www.example.com/?sdfuh&fbclid=azduh
- www.example.com/?sdfuh&fbclid=azduh
- example.com/?sdfuh&fbclid=azduh

They should return https://example.com/?sdfuh

Ok so after some help Ive got to this

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(?:^|&)fbclid=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ https://example.com/?%1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This works with:

- https://www.example.com/?sdfuh
- http://www.example.com/?sdfuh
- www.example.com/?sdfuh
- https://www.example.com/?sdfuh&fbclid=azduh
- http://www.example.com/?sdfuh&fbclid=azduh

Not with

- www.example.com/?sdfuh&fbclid=azduh
- example.com/?sdfuh&fbclid=azduh

I need to figure out how to make it shorter and work with all the possibilities

Comment: No i always want to get https://  but some links to the site have query strings for referrals ie example.com/?abc but because facebook also likes query strings if they come from facebook that piece removes there tag and puts it back to example.com/?abc     im trying to combine it so I always get https and the query string ?abc but if the fbclid= is there remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than literally combining the rules, I believe the main piece of knowledge you are missing out on is the use of `[OR]` - which means a `RewriteRule` won't fail if only one of the `RewriteCond` results in `true`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(?:^|&)fbclid=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ https://example.com/?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

---

You can test this out here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=f4381086-80b4-52b6-883e-8921f5de2316

Comment: This is proving very useful, thanks. The only issue I have now is I removed %2 from the Rewriterule as I only want the first not after fbclid. but when I did that it now grabs www. if fbclid isn't there and it wont always be there

Comment: I updates the question with a new set up and its almost perfect thanks I can only find two errors.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of help this solved my issue of stripping facebooks tracker, keeping my own query string and confirming https:// is used.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(?:^|&)fbclid=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ https://example.com/?%1%2 [R,N]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$2 [R,L]
```